# Firebase on Swift, how to get notified if a query is empty?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I am using firebase in swift and I am trying to search through my users by user name using a query like so:

```
InfoCenter.ref.child("users").queryOrderedByChild("username").queryEqualToValue(firstTextField.text)
            .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
```

This works great but I want to be notified if the query is empty aka the there is no user that has that user name. Can someone please show me how to edit how I format my search to allow for that? Thanks!

Edit:

My tree looks like this:

```
users:{

asdfasdfkl:{

username: "bob",

highscore: "1000"

}

}
```

upon changing event type to .Value, when using snapshot.value I no longer get the adjkadfjla ID. I now get the entire try below it

Comment: use observeEventType `.value` and than check `if snapshot.exists()` ..

Comment: check this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853533/firebase-how-to-get-the-key-value-in-observeeventtype-value/37853809#37853809

Comment: works great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if the snapshot exist, this will return a Bool

```
snapshot.exists()
```

Comment: now my snapshot.key results in "users" not the "adsfjaldsfkja" Id string

Comment: how to I get that Id string

Comment: .value gets me the whole entire person object. I want the Id

Comment: you need to loop through allkeys to get ids ... like `snapshot.value.allkeys()` something like that

Answer (score 0):

for Swift 5.0, it's been updated to `if (querySnapshot?.isEmpty == true) {}`