# How to get key of NSDictionary

Tags: swift, firebase, key, nsdictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase and getting a snapshot and when I print it I get this:

```
{
    "-KOx03Q1f1Tl9AiWxNlg" =     {
         message = ".";
         senderId = B6WI1xkEBXd4cwYkYFQRneEvPBV2;
    };
}
```

I want to get the key, the value of `-KOx03Q1f1Tl9AiWxNlg` key. I can't figure out how to get it.  I can print it as! `NSDictionary` and it looks exactly the same so it seems to be in that form...but I didn't know `NSDictionary` items had a key or name like that.  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37853809/4601170

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `NSDictionary`, so you can get array of all keys using `allKeys` property of `NSDictionary`

```
let keys = yourDic.allKeys as! [String]
```

**In Swift 2.2 and later**

```
let keys = myDictionary.keys as! [String]
```

**Note:** Access the first object of keys array to get `-KOx03Q1f1Tl9AiWxNlg` key.

Comment: Okay so that gives me this: ` let keys = snapshotDict!.allKeys as! [String]
print(keys[0])` is there an easier way or is this the best way?

Comment: **Yes**, you need to access that first object.

Comment: You can try with this:

let allKeys = Array(dictSelSection.keys)

Its for swift 4...and its working very fine...Hope it helps...!!!